# How to make a sticky navbar without JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I want to create a sticky navbar. It should float over the content during scrolling, and should be displayed before the content if the page is scrolled to the top.

My implementation has almost worked but the part of the content was overlapped by the navbar when the page was scrolled to the top.

I managed to get it to work with JS by updating the `padding-top` CSS property of `#content` every time the window size is changed (see the `fixContentPadding` function).

Can this be done without JS?

Here is an example:

```js
function fixContentPadding() {
  const navbarElement = document.getElementById("navbar");
  const contentElement = document.getElementById("content");

  contentElement.style.paddingTop = navbarElement.offsetHeight + "px";
}

document.addEventListener("resize", fixContentPadding);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fixContentPadding);
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

#content {
  min-height: 200vh;  /* to demonstrate scrolling */
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="/">Hello, World!</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried adding `margin-top: ;` to the `#content` element? From what I understood you just want a way to separate content from navbar right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) is for:

```css
#navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="/">Hello, World!</a>
</div>

<div id="content-container">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks really great and elegant but, unfortunately, it doesn't display the content at the full height, just first 100px. I have tried to set the `max-height` CSS-property of the container to 100% instead of 100px but in this case the navbar is not sticky (after several lines are scrolled, it starts to scroll together with the content). Maybe I have misunderstood something? Thank you.

Comment: I only added the container with `max-height` and `overflow` properties to ensure that the stack overflow snippet would scroll. You don't need either of them; you don't need the container element. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A margin-top on your div#content-container ?

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

#navbar *:hover {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

#navbar * {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#content-container {
  margin-top:40px;
}

#content {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0.01em 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="/">Hello, World!</a>
</div>

<div id="content-container">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fixContentPadding() {
  document.getElementById("content-container").style.paddingTop = document.getElementById("navbar").offsetHeight + 15 + "px";
}
window.onresize = fixContentPadding;
fixContentPadding();
```

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#navbar *:hover {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

#navbar * {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#content {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 3em auto auto auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0.01em 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="/">Hello, World!</a>
</div>

<div id="content-container">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p><p>Hello, World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

add a margin-top to the content div equal or alrger of the navbar hight.