# position sticky property not working in html

Tags: html, css

`position: sticky` is not working in my code

I have tried different properties but nothing seems to work

codepen: https://codepen.io/iabzeet/pen/qBmGyLb

help me solve this problem

```css
#title{
    font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(243, 30, 112);
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.logo{
    width: 4%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
 .top-container {
    padding: 60px 30px 30px 30px;
    margin: -80px -6px 0px -30px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,blue,white,yellow);
  } 



body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



#header-img{
  width: 3%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20%;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;

  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  li a:hover {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: -48px -6px 0px -10px;
    padding: 9px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }


#cover{

    margin: 0.5px -10px 0px -10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -98px;
    height: 550px;
    object-fit: cover;
    align-self: center;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.8;
}


.container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0.01em 16px;
    padding-top: 0.01em;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0.01em;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    justify-items: center;

}
#sml{
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(0px, 150px);
}
#text{
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  color: whitesmoke;
  transform: translate(0px, 150px);
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.policies{
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-image: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  
}
#prod{
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524230572899-a752b3835840?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1952&q=80");
  margin-right: -7px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 390px;
  font-size: large;
}

/* .centered{
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(228, 56, 56);
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<head>
    <title>Giovanni's Guitars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inknut+Antiqua:wght@300&display=swap"
        type='text/css'>
</head>



    <div class="top-container">
        <img class="logo" src="logo1.svg" alt="a logo">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Giovanni's Guitars</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <header id="header">   
        <img id="header-img" src="logo2.svg" alt="a logo">
   
        <nav id="nav-bar">

            <ul>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    

    </header> 

<div class="container">
    
    <video autoplay muted loop id="cover">
        <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2021-05/small_watermarked/210512_01_Music_4k_009_preview.webm" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <p id="sml">Since 1961</p>
    <div id="text">
        <h4>Guitars and Basses.</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="policies">
    <h5 id="prod">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel sint fugiat placeat mollitia necessitatibus enim quae at illo rem! Fuga tempore dicta ut repudiandae quis quaerat facere sit odit! Fugiat perspiciatis, accusamus voluptate itaque incidunt reprehenderit perferendis nemo. Consequuntur vero ipsum modi excepturi facilis id nemo, porro animi beatae est recusandae officia, repudiandae velit necessitatibus possimus nam maiores quo corporis laboriosam obcaecati repellat sit! Explicabo eveniet fugiat iste, minima facere ipsum aliquam fuga dignissimos amet aperiam atque excepturi, adipisci distinctio minus laudantium. Provident obcaecati tenetur rerum! Eveniet quo, nulla debitis, reiciendis hic fugiat perferendis vel consequatur eligendi amet assumenda totam? Ullam ipsa illum fugit, dolor est hic ex sequi laudantium odio consectetur vitae nihil unde, quibusdam necessitatibus. Quae placeat dolorum eos suscipit! Quo necessitatibus in ab delectus doloremque et ipsum dolorem, quod, accusantium voluptas, obcaecati possimus. Dolores dolor accusamus ex aspernatur! Porro quo laboriosam est blanditiis incidunt, quis accusantium necessitatibus distinctio dolorem enim ipsam accusamus ut odit officia rerum, praesentium ab voluptas fuga explicabo fugit dolorum ea cum animi in? Iusto veniam corporis doloremque, necessitatibus ipsam dolore! Quam sequi reprehenderit ex fugiat soluta facilis illum laudantium omnis assumenda quisquam, incidunt, deserunt officia nostrum perspiciatis. Labore veniam reiciendis quia eos veritatis sequi velit numquam unde molestias, adipisci, eligendi quisquam, quae quo modi porro harum commodi consequatur aliquid nobis. Natus quidem voluptate ratione fugiat, dolores quo culpa fuga fugit. Aperiam dolore, velit ullam repellat unde delectus eos aliquid, asperiores itaque impedit in sapiente, quasi facilis. Libero iusto cumque esse rerum quis, suscipit voluptatibus nihil soluta facere magni, nesciunt praesentium dolore consectetur et sapiente corrupti reprehenderit fuga facilis animi odio asperiores quod tempore? Possimus numquam mollitia nemo amet quod ut facere maxime facilis cupiditate optio, cum quisquam culpa accusantium harum dicta iste autem. Illo provident minima dolorum excepturi culpa perferendis laboriosam, fugiat reprehenderit magnam adipisci. Minus cumque magni harum! Minus earum aliquam porro explicabo fugiat fuga ipsa aut hic autem rerum ad provident corrupti, repellendus quam assumenda repudiandae? Quos inventore nam aliquam fugit totam modi fugiat asperiores cumque cum reprehenderit. Laborum iusto culpa facere velit inventore aperiam quia nisi, amet dolorem autem possimus explicabo enim vel dolore. Aut iusto amet consequatur saepe velit aliquam nihil nisi, quo iure veniam doloribus ducimus! Adipisci quisquam alias nisi eveniet! Repudiandae officia perspiciatis, neque accusantium cum suscipit fuga alias explicabo, corporis facere voluptatem assumenda fugiat incidunt dignissimos dicta ex tenetur magni sint ipsam ipsum. Provident suscipit quod asperiores labore esse sapiente nesciunt, iusto blanditiis aut distinctio sint rerum optio. Distinctio aspernatur eum natus assumenda! Molestias omnis fuga natus vitae eius ea, eligendi odit magni laboriosam id quis reprehenderit aspernatur expedita sunt. Ex praesentium facilis at, hic minus voluptatem laborum eaque, voluptatum ipsa incidunt tempora. Tempora vel dignissimos aspernatur rerum optio officia excepturi delectus, commodi ex itaque ab velit eaque pariatur sapiente placeat reprehenderit earum ipsum necessitatibus ullam! Hic maxime assumenda provident praesentium animi corrupti laboriosam dolores explicabo voluptas iure, quasi error dolore doloremque voluptatem molestias et accusamus officia id reprehenderit repellat quia ipsam, quo repudiandae. At, repudiandae aut! Itaque rerum natus nulla aperiam veniam et fugit ipsa, at reiciendis eos consectetur unde officia, impedit earum facere placeat nemo praesentium quos deserunt temporibus, nesciunt doloribus culpa ad? Eius repellat vel fugit, labore reprehenderit nesciunt tenetur maxime debitis tempore veniam, non et quibusdam deleniti laborum explicabo! Architecto quo perferendis doloribus ut magnam inventore alias temporibus voluptatem qui ratione neque itaque ex est atque, debitis quod voluptates error dolorum sapiente excepturi magni. Quis modi molestiae laborum magni odio maxime laudantium id sed labore enim facere est veritatis distinctio, quos asperiores minus delectus ratione earum ipsum a quo? Atque aliquid molestiae repellat veritatis corporis optio voluptas, sunt impedit eum nobis laboriosam expedita magni sed doloribus consectetur, quos ratione maxime saepe! Sapiente ea eligendi libero alias laborum voluptatem repellat consequuntur mollitia perspiciatis non dolorum, quas et repellendus. Repellat, doloribus alias quas rerum eveniet quo velit ullam dolorem quidem nesciunt ipsum cum exercitationem magni numquam provident neque nemo odio perferendis, sapiente ipsam sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Vitae, minima. Dolore quod quam similique, odio facere necessitatibus quas officia libero non eveniet sit ipsum consectetur sunt distinctio omnis dolor, doloremque quaerat, labore quia fugiat porro facilis inventore! Nulla magnam labore assumenda laboriosam incidunt nisi dignissimos maxime repudiandae, maiores ipsa quod eligendi, at nesciunt quos. Commodi vitae blanditiis ratione assumenda. Voluptatem placeat provident illum officia fugit sequi vero nisi quam. Ipsum rerum eius ratione ea asperiores possimus praesentium commodi fuga, minima eum laudantium suscipit nostrum eveniet perferendis deserunt laboriosam blanditiis neque, alias, voluptatem eligendi dolorum vitae quae! Aut amet aliquid libero pariatur, blanditiis harum atque. Necessitatibus, iure? Odio quae magnam aliquid incidunt officia error perspiciatis illum voluptatum hic? Quas alias nemo accusantium temporibus error? Provident fuga fugiat eius enim totam soluta saepe beatae accusantium asperiores sunt nesciunt ipsa, eaque dolorum et perspiciatis dignissimos sequi? Adipisci dolorem doloremque facere pariatur inventore fuga cupiditate vel quidem enim a quia, ab odio, eveniet dignissimos dolores aliquid tenetur autem, quis nam quibusdam. Vel, quam excepturi. Fugit maxime voluptatum nam maiores delectus, quo illo consequatur aliquid dolorem excepturi quia sit laudantium quam deserunt numquam adipisci voluptatem eveniet voluptates, sed veniam rem reprehenderit corporis? Blanditiis quod, aut consequuntur commodi nisi, cupiditate dolor nihil aperiam deserunt quaerat molestiae quis nesciunt, laborum unde incidunt culpa! Possimus commodi impedit ullam eius aut veritatis expedita voluptatum nam deserunt ipsa, eum consequatur iusto doloribus enim voluptas labore ut nobis obcaecati illo perspiciatis quam similique provident. Culpa, quos sint eveniet eaque sequi doloremque mollitia nesciunt alias maiores debitis natus soluta. Explicabo dolorum ipsum dolores quaerat doloribus ad commodi nulla cupiditate doloremque. Quas iusto velit pariatur voluptatibus labore? Assumenda, cumque! Dicta molestias, harum officiis aperiam velit temporibus optio obcaecati nemo sint quam debitis nostrum. Esse, dolor. Excepturi provident ea ab, quas fugiat, dolores magni sapiente ipsum, accusantium commodi ex itaque enim! Beatae odio ipsa quisquam enim eius expedita obcaecati doloribus libero illum minima dolor asperiores accusantium, saepe suscipit facilis consequatur laboriosam, optio nemo cupiditate commodi necessitatibus aperiam. Enim perferendis ullam cum beatae soluta quas aspernatur labore itaque veniam delectus dolor debitis, voluptatibus veritatis deserunt nihil blanditiis velit ex obcaecati necessitatibus officiis minima omnis odit. Explicabo est consequuntur, ea nemo asperiores placeat nisi cum fugiat reiciendis repudiandae unde ipsum, distinctio nesciunt eos eligendi. Quo provident atque aperiam nemo numquam quaerat aliquid! Quibusdam culpa obcaecati quaerat excepturi veniam! Ut aliquam dolorum vitae praesentium reprehenderit? Unde hic consequatur officia, amet doloremque expedita! Voluptas accusamus animi ipsum quisquam atque et, ducimus est sequi quos quibusdam, nulla omnis, magnam debitis molestiae sit eius soluta impedit iusto esse voluptatem minus fugiat dolor provident? Adipisci ipsam eos, id ad accusamus voluptates accusantium maiores quas quos nobis, optio culpa assumenda similique voluptatum rem dolorum veniam doloremque ducimus quasi sit. Quos blanditiis natus in nisi sint illo unde inventore repudiandae, beatae eius ut vero ex at veritatis dolor itaque obcaecati adipisci. Itaque beatae omnis tempora et eos debitis, amet incidunt consequuntur aut aliquid, porro distinctio expedita repellat tempore. Similique iste dolores excepturi esse laborum ad, asperiores voluptate. Cum harum aliquid alias qui perferendis magnam maiores eligendi expedita et sapiente quibusdam animi unde minus, mollitia nihil repellat delectus cupiditate, architecto eveniet! Modi iusto vero molestiae laudantium, corporis optio a vel perspiciatis quisquam alias maiores ratione, ea ipsam id quam dolorem quis consequuntur. Excepturi at explicabo doloremque asperiores cupiditate? Cum sunt dolorem similique eveniet eligendi, obcaecati nesciunt vel perspiciatis delectus magnam, illum doloribus aut amet ipsam veritatis laboriosam quidem alias illo saepe rerum! Et dicta quo tempore eos dolore? Iste hic recusandae, blanditiis cumque veniam quas architecto. Repudiandae aliquam necessitatibus magni rerum quisquam eum atque dolorum placeat dignissimos. A qui cumque voluptates sint optio voluptatibus vitae harum tenetur reiciendis id eos quidem tempore laborum in error obcaecati odit ex et ratione, eaque assumenda aut eius! Impedit, quis. Nulla inventore neque omnis qui eveniet molestias eius sint vel voluptas! Tempora, animi? Sequi veniam iure quibusdam repellat, dolorum, id earum accusamus reiciendis at possimus adipisci a similique?</h5>
</section>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Could you move the <body> tag in your code below the </head> closing tag? It would help to create a better document structure.

Comment: _Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning. The element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned._ [Source Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Working Demo: https://codepen.io/shalinimandal/pen/dyWEgpg

Add the following CSS in your code:

```
nav {
  z-index: 10;
  
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Add this Javascript code to add sticky class on scroll

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can't it be done without any javascript? Though I can understand the code a bit I am not familiar with js yet

Comment: If we want to do it without JS then the nav-bar will always be sticky at top:0. So, we cannot have any other element before nav. It has to be the first element on the page. Check Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458661/how-to-make-a-sticky-navbar-using-only-html-and-css-without-js

Comment: Check out MaxiGui's answer(code). It seems to be working as I desired without js for the sticky part. But I'm gonna use your js for I want that parallax effect

Answer (score 1):

As I said in  comment of your question:

> Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning. The element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned. [Source Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

It does solve entirely your problem:

- First I took out the `nav` from the header to make the `position:sticky` work because it wont work if it is not directly under body in this case.
- Second I just commented your `position:fixed` on your `#cover` to show where that it can work otherwise it will always cancel your sticky as per documentation
- Third I added `z-index:1000; /* ADDED */` on your `nav`
- Fourth comment postion on `.policies` and `#prod`

Now you just need to align correctly your video, as it seems to have a lot of different margin for no reason

DEMO:

```css
#title{
    font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(243, 30, 112);
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.logo{
    width: 4%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
 .top-container {
    padding: 60px 30px 30px 30px;
    margin: -80px -6px 0px -30px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,blue,white,yellow);
  } 



body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



#header-img{
  width: 3%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
  z-index:1000; /* ADDED */
  
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20%;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;

  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  li a:hover {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: -48px -6px 0px -10px;
    padding: 9px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }


#cover{

    margin: 0.5px -10px 0px -10px;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    top: 0px;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -98px;
    height: 550px;
    object-fit: cover;
    align-self: center;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.8;
}


.container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0.01em 16px;
    padding-top: 0.01em;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0.01em;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    justify-items: center;

}
#sml{
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(0px, 150px);
}
#text{
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  color: whitesmoke;
  transform: translate(0px, 150px);
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.policies{
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-image: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  /*position: relative;*/
  
}
#prod{
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524230572899-a752b3835840?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1952&q=80");
  margin-right: -7px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 390px;
  font-size: large;
}

/* .centered{
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(228, 56, 56);
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<head>
    <title>Giovanni's Guitars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inknut+Antiqua:wght@300&display=swap"
        type='text/css'>
</head>



    <div class="top-container">
        <img class="logo" src="logo1.svg" alt="a logo">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Giovanni's Guitars</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <header id="header">   
        <img id="header-img" src="logo2.svg" alt="a logo">
   
        

    </header> 
    <nav id="nav-bar">

            <ul>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    
<div class="container">
    
    <video autoplay muted loop id="cover">
        <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2021-05/small_watermarked/210512_01_Music_4k_009_preview.webm" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <p id="sml">Since 1961</p>
    <div id="text">
        <h4>Guitars and Basses.</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="policies">
    <h5 id="prod">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel sint fugiat placeat mollitia necessitatibus enim quae at illo rem! Fuga tempore dicta ut repudiandae quis quaerat facere sit odit! Fugiat perspiciatis, accusamus voluptate itaque incidunt reprehenderit perferendis nemo. Consequuntur vero ipsum modi excepturi facilis id nemo, porro animi beatae est recusandae officia, repudiandae velit necessitatibus possimus nam maiores quo corporis laboriosam obcaecati repellat sit! Explicabo eveniet fugiat iste, minima facere ipsum aliquam fuga dignissimos amet aperiam atque excepturi, adipisci distinctio minus laudantium. Provident obcaecati tenetur rerum! Eveniet quo, nulla debitis, reiciendis hic fugiat perferendis vel consequatur eligendi amet assumenda totam? Ullam ipsa illum fugit, dolor est hic ex sequi laudantium odio consectetur vitae nihil unde, quibusdam necessitatibus. Quae placeat dolorum eos suscipit! Quo necessitatibus in ab delectus doloremque et ipsum dolorem, quod, accusantium voluptas, obcaecati possimus. Dolores dolor accusamus ex aspernatur! Porro quo laboriosam est blanditiis incidunt, quis accusantium necessitatibus distinctio dolorem enim ipsam accusamus ut odit officia rerum, praesentium ab voluptas fuga explicabo fugit dolorum ea cum animi in? Iusto veniam corporis doloremque, necessitatibus ipsam dolore! Quam sequi reprehenderit ex fugiat soluta facilis illum laudantium omnis assumenda quisquam, incidunt, deserunt officia nostrum perspiciatis. Labore veniam reiciendis quia eos veritatis sequi velit numquam unde molestias, adipisci, eligendi quisquam, quae quo modi porro harum commodi consequatur aliquid nobis. Natus quidem voluptate ratione fugiat, dolores quo culpa fuga fugit. Aperiam dolore, velit ullam repellat unde delectus eos aliquid, asperiores itaque impedit in sapiente, quasi facilis. Libero iusto cumque esse rerum quis, suscipit voluptatibus nihil soluta facere magni, nesciunt praesentium dolore consectetur et sapiente corrupti reprehenderit fuga facilis animi odio asperiores quod tempore? Possimus numquam mollitia nemo amet quod ut facere maxime facilis cupiditate optio, cum quisquam culpa accusantium harum dicta iste autem. Illo provident minima dolorum excepturi culpa perferendis laboriosam, fugiat reprehenderit magnam adipisci. Minus cumque magni harum! Minus earum aliquam porro explicabo fugiat fuga ipsa aut hic autem rerum ad provident corrupti, repellendus quam assumenda repudiandae? Quos inventore nam aliquam fugit totam modi fugiat asperiores cumque cum reprehenderit. Laborum iusto culpa facere velit inventore aperiam quia nisi, amet dolorem autem possimus explicabo enim vel dolore. Aut iusto amet consequatur saepe velit aliquam nihil nisi, quo iure veniam doloribus ducimus! Adipisci quisquam alias nisi eveniet! Repudiandae officia perspiciatis, neque accusantium cum suscipit fuga alias explicabo, corporis facere voluptatem assumenda fugiat incidunt dignissimos dicta ex tenetur magni sint ipsam ipsum. Provident suscipit quod asperiores labore esse sapiente nesciunt, iusto blanditiis aut distinctio sint rerum optio. Distinctio aspernatur eum natus assumenda! Molestias omnis fuga natus vitae eius ea, eligendi odit magni laboriosam id quis reprehenderit aspernatur expedita sunt. Ex praesentium facilis at, hic minus voluptatem laborum eaque, voluptatum ipsa incidunt tempora. Tempora vel dignissimos aspernatur rerum optio officia excepturi delectus, commodi ex itaque ab velit eaque pariatur sapiente placeat reprehenderit earum ipsum necessitatibus ullam! Hic maxime assumenda provident praesentium animi corrupti laboriosam dolores explicabo voluptas iure, quasi error dolore doloremque voluptatem molestias et accusamus officia id reprehenderit repellat quia ipsam, quo repudiandae. At, repudiandae aut! Itaque rerum natus nulla aperiam veniam et fugit ipsa, at reiciendis eos consectetur unde officia, impedit earum facere placeat nemo praesentium quos deserunt temporibus, nesciunt doloribus culpa ad? Eius repellat vel fugit, labore reprehenderit nesciunt tenetur maxime debitis tempore veniam, non et quibusdam deleniti laborum explicabo! Architecto quo perferendis doloribus ut magnam inventore alias temporibus voluptatem qui ratione neque itaque ex est atque, debitis quod voluptates error dolorum sapiente excepturi magni. Quis modi molestiae laborum magni odio maxime laudantium id sed labore enim facere est veritatis distinctio, quos asperiores minus delectus ratione earum ipsum a quo? Atque aliquid molestiae repellat veritatis corporis optio voluptas, sunt impedit eum nobis laboriosam expedita magni sed doloribus consectetur, quos ratione maxime saepe! Sapiente ea eligendi libero alias laborum voluptatem repellat consequuntur mollitia perspiciatis non dolorum, quas et repellendus. Repellat, doloribus alias quas rerum eveniet quo velit ullam dolorem quidem nesciunt ipsum cum exercitationem magni numquam provident neque nemo odio perferendis, sapiente ipsam sunt.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Vitae, minima. Dolore quod quam similique, odio facere necessitatibus quas officia libero non eveniet sit ipsum consectetur sunt distinctio omnis dolor, doloremque quaerat, labore quia fugiat porro facilis inventore! Nulla magnam labore assumenda laboriosam incidunt nisi dignissimos maxime repudiandae, maiores ipsa quod eligendi, at nesciunt quos. Commodi vitae blanditiis ratione assumenda. Voluptatem placeat provident illum officia fugit sequi vero nisi quam. Ipsum rerum eius ratione ea asperiores possimus praesentium commodi fuga, minima eum laudantium suscipit nostrum eveniet perferendis deserunt laboriosam blanditiis neque, alias, voluptatem eligendi dolorum vitae quae! Aut amet aliquid libero pariatur, blanditiis harum atque. Necessitatibus, iure? Odio quae magnam aliquid incidunt officia error perspiciatis illum voluptatum hic? Quas alias nemo accusantium temporibus error? Provident fuga fugiat eius enim totam soluta saepe beatae accusantium asperiores sunt nesciunt ipsa, eaque dolorum et perspiciatis dignissimos sequi? Adipisci dolorem doloremque facere pariatur inventore fuga cupiditate vel quidem enim a quia, ab odio, eveniet dignissimos dolores aliquid tenetur autem, quis nam quibusdam. Vel, quam excepturi. Fugit maxime voluptatum nam maiores delectus, quo illo consequatur aliquid dolorem excepturi quia sit laudantium quam deserunt numquam adipisci voluptatem eveniet voluptates, sed veniam rem reprehenderit corporis? Blanditiis quod, aut consequuntur commodi nisi, cupiditate dolor nihil aperiam deserunt quaerat molestiae quis nesciunt, laborum unde incidunt culpa! Possimus commodi impedit ullam eius aut veritatis expedita voluptatum nam deserunt ipsa, eum consequatur iusto doloribus enim voluptas labore ut nobis obcaecati illo perspiciatis quam similique provident. Culpa, quos sint eveniet eaque sequi doloremque mollitia nesciunt alias maiores debitis natus soluta. Explicabo dolorum ipsum dolores quaerat doloribus ad commodi nulla cupiditate doloremque. Quas iusto velit pariatur voluptatibus labore? Assumenda, cumque! Dicta molestias, harum officiis aperiam velit temporibus optio obcaecati nemo sint quam debitis nostrum. Esse, dolor. Excepturi provident ea ab, quas fugiat, dolores magni sapiente ipsum, accusantium commodi ex itaque enim! Beatae odio ipsa quisquam enim eius expedita obcaecati doloribus libero illum minima dolor asperiores accusantium, saepe suscipit facilis consequatur laboriosam, optio nemo cupiditate commodi necessitatibus aperiam. Enim perferendis ullam cum beatae soluta quas aspernatur labore itaque veniam delectus dolor debitis, voluptatibus veritatis deserunt nihil blanditiis velit ex obcaecati necessitatibus officiis minima omnis odit. Explicabo est consequuntur, ea nemo asperiores placeat nisi cum fugiat reiciendis repudiandae unde ipsum, distinctio nesciunt eos eligendi. Quo provident atque aperiam nemo numquam quaerat aliquid! Quibusdam culpa obcaecati quaerat excepturi veniam! Ut aliquam dolorum vitae praesentium reprehenderit? Unde hic consequatur officia, amet doloremque expedita! Voluptas accusamus animi ipsum quisquam atque et, ducimus est sequi quos quibusdam, nulla omnis, magnam debitis molestiae sit eius soluta impedit iusto esse voluptatem minus fugiat dolor provident? Adipisci ipsam eos, id ad accusamus voluptates accusantium maiores quas quos nobis, optio culpa assumenda similique voluptatum rem dolorum veniam doloremque ducimus quasi sit. Quos blanditiis natus in nisi sint illo unde inventore repudiandae, beatae eius ut vero ex at veritatis dolor itaque obcaecati adipisci. Itaque beatae omnis tempora et eos debitis, amet incidunt consequuntur aut aliquid, porro distinctio expedita repellat tempore. Similique iste dolores excepturi esse laborum ad, asperiores voluptate. Cum harum aliquid alias qui perferendis magnam maiores eligendi expedita et sapiente quibusdam animi unde minus, mollitia nihil repellat delectus cupiditate, architecto eveniet! Modi iusto vero molestiae laudantium, corporis optio a vel perspiciatis quisquam alias maiores ratione, ea ipsam id quam dolorem quis consequuntur. Excepturi at explicabo doloremque asperiores cupiditate? Cum sunt dolorem similique eveniet eligendi, obcaecati nesciunt vel perspiciatis delectus magnam, illum doloribus aut amet ipsam veritatis laboriosam quidem alias illo saepe rerum! Et dicta quo tempore eos dolore? Iste hic recusandae, blanditiis cumque veniam quas architecto. Repudiandae aliquam necessitatibus magni rerum quisquam eum atque dolorum placeat dignissimos. A qui cumque voluptates sint optio voluptatibus vitae harum tenetur reiciendis id eos quidem tempore laborum in error obcaecati odit ex et ratione, eaque assumenda aut eius! Impedit, quis. Nulla inventore neque omnis qui eveniet molestias eius sint vel voluptas! Tempora, animi? Sequi veniam iure quibusdam repellat, dolorum, id earum accusamus reiciendis at possimus adipisci a similique?</h5>
</section>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Why is that `nav` moving along with the white space after scrolling??

Comment: @Parvat.R it was due to position type on `.policies` block

Comment: Thanks for this. But I want the video to be fixed in the background while text scrolls past it. I know it's asking too much but can you tell me how can it be done

Comment: @Abhijeet you want to have the video behind the `section.policies` when you scroll ? (if yes then this section should be in same section with the video)

Comment: I will try that

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove `position: fixed` from `#cover` and `position: absolute` from `#prod`

```css
#title{
    font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(243, 30, 112);
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.logo{
    width: 4%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
 .top-container {
    padding: 60px 30px 30px 30px;
    margin: -80px -6px 0px -30px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,blue,white,yellow);
  } 



body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, header, .container {
display:initial;
}

#header-img{
  width: 3%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  z-index: 10;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20%;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;

  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  li a:hover {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: -48px -6px 0px -10px;
    padding: 9px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }


#cover{

    margin: 0.5px -10px 0px -10px;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    top: 0px;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -98px;
    height: 550px;
    object-fit: cover;
    align-self: center;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.8;
}


.container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0.01em 16px;
    padding-top: 0.01em;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0.01em;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    justify-items: center;

}
#sml{
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(0px, 150px);
}
#text{
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  color: whitesmoke;
  transform: translate(0px, 150px);
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.policies{
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-image: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  
}
#prod{
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524230572899-a752b3835840?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1952&q=80");
  margin-right: -7px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 390px;
  font-size: large;
}

/* .centered{
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(228, 56, 56);
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
} */
```

```html
<body>




    <div class="top-container">
        <img class="logo" src="logo1.svg" alt="a logo">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Giovanni's Guitars</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <header id="header">   
        <img id="header-img" src="logo2.svg" alt="a logo">
   
        <nav id="nav-bar">

            <ul>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    

    </header> 

<div class="container">
    
    <video autoplay muted loop id="cover">
        <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2021-05/small_watermarked/210512_01_Music_4k_009_preview.webm" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <p id="sml">Since 1961</p>
    <div id="text">
        <h4>Guitars and Basses.</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<section class="policies">
    <h5 id="prod">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel sint fugiat placeat mollitia necessitatibus enim quae at illo rem! Fuga tempore dicta ut repudiandae quis quaerat facere sit odit! Fugiat perspiciatis, accusamus voluptate itaque incidunt reprehenderit perferendis nemo. Consequuntur vero ipsum modi excepturi facilis id nemo, porro animi beatae est recusandae officia, repudiandae velit necessitatibus possimus nam maiores quo corporis laboriosam obcaecati repellat sit! Explicabo eveniet fugiat iste, minima facere ipsum aliquam fuga dignissimos amet aperiam atque excepturi, adipisci distinctio minus laudantium. Provident obcaecati tenetur rerum! Eveniet quo, nulla debitis, reiciendis hic fugiat perferendis vel consequatur eligendi amet assumenda totam? Ullam ipsa illum fugit, dolor est hic ex sequi laudantium odio consectetur vitae nihil unde, quibusdam necessitatibus. Quae placeat dolorum eos suscipit! Quo necessitatibus in ab delectus doloremque et ipsum dolorem, quod, accusantium voluptas, obcaecati possimus. Dolores dolor accusamus ex aspernatur! Porro quo laboriosam est blanditiis incidunt, quis accusantium necessitatibus distinctio dolorem enim ipsam accusamus ut odit officia rerum, praesentium ab voluptas fuga explicabo fugit dolorum ea cum animi in? Iusto veniam corporis doloremque, necessitatibus ipsam dolore! Quam sequi reprehenderit ex fugiat soluta facilis illum laudantium omnis assumenda quisquam, incidunt, deserunt officia nostrum perspiciatis. Labore veniam reiciendis quia eos veritatis sequi velit numquam unde molestias, adipisci, eligendi quisquam, quae quo modi porro harum commodi consequatur aliquid nobis. Natus quidem voluptate ratione fugiat, dolores quo culpa fuga fugit. Aperiam dolore, velit ullam repellat unde delectus eos aliquid, asperiores itaque impedit in sapiente, quasi facilis. Libero iusto cumque esse rerum quis, suscipit voluptatibus nihil soluta facere magni, nesciunt praesentium dolore consectetur et sapiente corrupti reprehenderit fuga facilis animi odio 
    </h5>
    </section>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `position: sticky` doesn't work the way you think it does. The element  with the `position: sticky` will only be "stuck" as long as its parent is visible. In your case `nav` parent is `header` and `header` has roughly the same height than `nav`.

In other words if you want an element to stick it needs to be the child of the element you're scrolling into.

The problem in your case is that so many elements are positioned with `absolute` or `fixed` at the end your body has the same height as the header wich means no overflow and no "stickiness"

My advise would be to start over if possible, avoid `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` for the layout (I usually recommend `display: grid` but when I see the final result `display: block` should do) and apply `position: sticky` to the header

Answer (score 0):

I tested a bit and I think the problem is not with the position sticky but with where your nav is located in the html.

if you move it outside the header you will see that it already sticks a little. The problem is that it can only stick to the top of its container as long as it doesn't touch the bottom of the container. So the height of the container should be bigger for you nav to be able to move.

Answer (score -1):

Could you add some more detail on how you want the desired design to behave.

Do you wish to have the navbar stop when it hits to the top of the page? If so you will likely require some JavaScript. In which case, this may be what you are looking for...
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

If you simply wish for the navbar to stay where it is whilst the rest of the page moves behind it, then try this...

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I did not downvote but I guess it is because he wants to have the navbar like 200px from the top at the start of the page and then then when it arrives to the navbar it should stay on the top of the browser, but this is way, this is surely not gonna work, specialy if you just modify your the position, the navbar disapear as it is `top:0`. So it wont work, copy the snippet in the question and try, you will see...

Comment: @fatchild Apologies, I downvoted the answer but forgot to add a comment. The reason I downvoted is that position: fixed on its own (without further js or css) will simply place the navbar at the top of the page. The problem lies with the fact that so many elements are position fixed or absolute, which make the page height (as far as the nav element is concerned) too small to be sticky.